# Jmeter - Ant - NoHttpResponseException

Tags: ant, jmeter

I have a JMeter test which i have been using for more than 6 months.
Currently I have been running this via command line (no ANT) in non GUI mode.

This is what i do when i run via command line

```
"%JMETER_HOME%\bin\jmeter.bat" -n -t %TESTNAME% -p %PROPPATH% -l %RESULTPATH% -j %LOGPATH% -Djmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -Djmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true
```

I recently thought of using Ant. Whenever I run the same test (ofcourse for testing the same application) - I get below error.

```
Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException - Non HTTP response message: The target server failed to respond
```

There is no issue with the application and the application works perfectly fine - no exception in the log.
If I do not use Ant - the error disappears. I tried again and again - w/ Ant & w/o Ant - 5 times.
I get the error consistently when i use Ant.

I always the save the result in XML format, pass the same property files. No other differences.

This is from my Ant build file.

```
    <jmeter
        jmeterhome="${jmeter.home}"
        testplan ="${test.path}/${test.name}.jmx"
        resultlog="${test.result.path}/${test.name}.jtl"
        jmeterproperties="${test.properties}/${property.file.name}.properties"
        jmeterlogfile="${test.result.log}/jmeter.log"
        >
        <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format" value="xml"/>
        <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results" value="all"/>
        <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts" value="true"/>
        <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes" value="true"/>
        <property name="file_format.testlog" value="2.1"/>
        <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error" value="false"/>
        <property name="includecontroller.prefix" value="${basedir}/test/modules/"/>
    </jmeter>
```

I have no idea what is wrong here.

Also the issue i am facing with Ant happens only after 15 mins of run. not immediately. Looks like something related with memory...not sure.

**EDIT::**

As Dimitri has said, This is the available memory i have

Command line = 499Mb

Ant          = 247Mb

Environment variable in the machine

ANT_OPTS=-Xmx1024m -Xms512m
This is the machine detail where i run my test with 200 users.
[image]

Comment: Try adding following line between last `<property> and `</jmeter>`
`<jvmarg value="-Xmx4G"/>` or what is abour 70%-80% of available physical memory of your load generator host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My expectation is that you're missing the following stanza in command-line mode:

```
jmeterproperties="${test.properties}/${property.file.name}.properties"
```

I bet that **host** is defined under that ".properties" file and JMeter in command-line mode doesn't read this file.

Command line equivalent will be `-p` or `-q` option.

```
    -p, --propfile <argument>
            the jmeter property file to use
    -q, --addprop <argument>
            additional JMeter property file(s)
```

Alternatively you can set properties via `-J` command line argument as

```
jmeter -Jproperty1name=property1value -Jproperty2name=property2value -n -t ...
```

Third option is to put everything in `jmeter.properties` or `user.properties` file which live under /bin folder of your JMeter installation.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more details.

Comment: I updated the question..plz check once again... for your question...nope I pass the same property files in non-GUI mode as well (updated above).  Also the issue happens after 15 mins of running the test..not happens immediately...

Comment: Try adding `<jvmarg value="-Xmx4G/>` to your `jmeter` task definition.

Comment: Sure.. I will do and update you. Why do we need that for Ant? just curious

Comment: Actually Java Heap size should be the same for command line and Ant modes, however your environment can have some tweaks like `JVM_ARGS` modified in JMeter startup script or environment variable.

You can check it by creating a new test plan with only one Beanshell Sampler containing following line: `log.info("Available memory: " + Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 1024 + " Mb");` which will print out the amount of memory available to Java to "jmeter.log" and compare output for Ant and command-line run options

Comment: Thanks Dimitri. I had to attach an image. so i updated the question - Plz check the EDIt section. lloks like ANt available < commandline mode. I will try to update it with jvmargs. Also.. with 499Mb- how many concurrent threads i can go upto?  I know it depends. But i want an approximate number if possible.

Comment: For 32-bit OS and JVM you won't be able to allocate > 2G to Ant/Java. JMeter task doesn't respect your ANT_OPTS so set appropriate value via `jvmarg` parameter. If it used to work with 499Mb relevant setting will be `<jvmarg value="-Xmx512M"/>. You should be able to spawn around 100 concurrent threads this way, just consider following recommendations from http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips guide.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am really sorry to bug you with my questions. Even when i set <jvmarg value="-Xmx512M"/> for JMeter i did not work. Then I set the ANT_OPTS=Xmx512m in environment variables. It works fine now. What does it mean? Does ANT also need more memory for this? By using ANT i seem to use more system resources..rt? I think i can come up with .bat file instead of ANT. Please suggest.

Comment: I'm surprised that `jvmarg` amendment didn't work. It doesn't indicate that ANT is more memory consuming, however default Java Heap size settings may be different for command line ant Ant modes. The idea was to provide enough Heap so JMeter could do its work. I'm happy that you've managed to achieve it via ANT_OPTS.